# when i run npx expo run:android i get this error Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: react-native, expo

[Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iywv.png)
Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-google-signin_google-signin:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-google-signin_google-signin:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4b1308f73665eeac924c132c45e496df\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4b1308f73665eeac924c132c45e496df\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation